# deferred.resolve giving error TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I am using angularjs and cordova tool for creating application.

I have created service, which contains code for calling APIs. and in that I want to return response to my angular controller.

My code is,
Service,

```
JodoModule.factory('commonServices', function ($http, $q, $rootScope) {
    return {
        getServiceData: function (url) {
            $rootScope.loading = true;
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: url
            }

            $http(req).success(function (data) {
                alert("data in service = " + JSON.stringify(data.Data));
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.reject(status);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

My controller is,

```
commonServices.getServiceData("My url").
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert(data);
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Got error");
            });
```

In above code, in service, its showing elert message for JSON.stringify(data.Data)); in success block, so data is comming, but its not executing deferred.resolve(data); properly...

**in Web tool bar its giving me error,**
**`ie. TypeError: undefined is not a function`**

**My o/p is :**

```
{"status":"SUCCESS","Message":"success","Token":"","Data":[{"Id":17,"UserId":"477f1919-6b80-4804-a325-ac0cb05bcd3e","UserName":"honey","FirstName":"honey","LastName":null,"ProfilePic":false,"Status":2}]}
```

How can I solve this error. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinary $q promises don't have a `.success()` or `.error()` method, but you shouldn't be using the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) anyway. Instead, do this:

```
JodoModule.factory('commonServices', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    return {
        getServiceData: function (url) {
            $rootScope.loading = true;
            var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: url
            };

            return $http(req).then(function (result) {
                alert("data in service = " + JSON.stringify(result.data.Data));
                return result.data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Controller:

```
commonServices.getServiceData("My url").
        then(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }).
        catch(function (result) {
            alert("Got error");
        });
```

Quite a bit cleaner, ay?

Comment: Can you tell me what is catch here... ?
Because it is giving me JavaScript error with : 
The use of keyword as identifier is invalid.

Comment: Your solution is working, 
I am using this code in controller,
commonServices.getServiceData("URL").
        then(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });

Please specify, what is catch keyword in your given solution...
Everything else is working...
Thanks... cheers :)
Saved time...

Comment: @KevalPatel `catch` is described in the $q documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api